# Three quiet men

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay

> See me on one
> after a second din
> I'm the third man
> I stopped solving at four
> and I'm on five

Hint

> B

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is the four-letter word:

> **ABEL**

*See me on one*

> An image of the US President, Abraham Lincoln - i.e. "**Abe L**" - appears *on* the [US *one*-cent coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(United_States_coin)).

*after a second din*

> Write 'ABEL' *after* the *second* letter of the English alphabet (B) to get B+ABEL=**BABEL**, a word meaning 'din' (a confused noise made by a number of voices).

*I'm the third man*

> The third man according to Genesis was **[ABEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel)**, the son of Adam and the younger brother of Cain.

*I stopped solving at four*

> In mathematics, [**Abel's impossibility theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) (also known as the Abel-Ruffini theorem) states that there is 'no solution in radicals to general polynomial equations of degree five or higher with arbitrary coefficients'. In other words, it *stops solving at [degree] four*.

*and I'm on five*

> An image of the US President, Abraham Lincoln - i.e. "**Abe L**" - appears *on* the [US *five*-dollar bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_five-dollar_bill), as well as on the penny!

As for the Hint:

> This singular letter 'B' represents **a [Bel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)**, the base unit of measurement for the intensity of sound (most usually expressed in 'decibels').

The title relates to...

> ...the three men referenced in this puzzle: Abraham Lincoln, Abel in the Bible, and the mathematician [Niels Henrik Abel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel). They are 'quiet' because in sound intensity terms they are only 'a bel' - very quiet indeed!

Comment: thanks! I was puzzling on that one for DAYS and I was considering wordplay but nice :)